# Android talkback element type announcement

Tags: android, talkback

I am trying to make my app more accessible. I am having a hard time finding helpful things because there isn't a lot of documentation (at least I could not find it).

In my app, Talkback does not announce the element type for ImageViews. What I basically want is for Talkback to announce my contentDescription for the ImageView and follow it up with ", Image".

This link states that " Many accessibility services, such as TalkBack and BrailleBack, automatically announce an element's type after announcing its label, so you shouldn't include element types in your labels. For example, "submit" is a good label for a Button object, but "submitButton" isn't a good label." but it does not specify which element types it announces and which it does not. 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/apps.html

1. Does anyone have any idea if Talkback announces "Image" after the contentDescription for ImageViews?
2. When does Talkback announce a link as a "Link"? Or is it the developer's responsibility to add it at the end of the contentDescription? Can I make talkback announce clickable text as a "Link"?

Any help/information/pointers is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A: don't add stuff to the end of the content description.  It is an accessibility violation and in almost ALL circumstances just makes things less acessible (will explain more later).

B: A lot of contextual things are communicated to TalkBack users via earcons (bips, beeps, etc), you may just not be noticing.

C: Yes, this is confusing and difficult to determine, no images are not announced, though I think this is for good reason.  For example, an image with a click listener may just be a fancy styled button.  In iOS there are traits for you to change for this, Android has omitted this highly useful feature, so we're stuck with odd workarounds.  The ideal solution would be for the Accessibility APIs to allow the developer to communicate this information.

As for links, typically inline links in text views are announced (basically anything android detects and underlines automatically), but otherwise are not.  So, in practice A LOT of links are missed.

Now, as for when you should/should not supply this information yourself.  If unsure, just don't and you'll obtain a reasonably high level of accessibility by following the above guidelines.  In fact, any of the considerations below are really just fighting the Android OS limitations, and are their problem!  However, the Android Accessibility Ecosystem is very weak, and if you want to provide a higher level of accessibility, it is understandable, however, difficult!  In your attempts you can actually end up working against yourself.  Let me explain:

In Accessibility there is a line between providing information and consistency.  By adding contextual information to a content description you are walking along this line.  What if Google said "We're not going to share contextual information, add it yourself!".

You would have buttons in music players across different music playing apps that announce in TalkBack like this:

App1: "Play, Button"

App2: "Play, Actionable"

App3: "Play, Clickable"

Do we have consistency here?  Now a final example!

App4: "Play, Double Tap to click if you're on TalkBack, Hit enter if you're a keyboard user, use your select key for SwitchAccess users....."

Notice how complicated App4's Play Button is, this is illustrating that the information that TalkBack is using is NOT JUST FOR TALKBACK.  The accessibility information from you app is consumed by a multitude of Accessibility services.  When you "Hack" contextual information onto a content description, sure it might sound better for a TalkBack user, but what have you done to Braille Back users?  To SwitchAccess users?  In general, the content description of an element should describe the element, and leave contextual information for TalkBack to calculate/users to figure out given proximity to other controls.

TO ANSWER YOUR TWO PARTICULAR ISSUES (Images and Links):

What I recommend for images is in the content description make it obvious that the thing your describing is an image.

Let's say you have a picture of a kitten.

BAD: A kitten, Image

Good: A picture of a kitten.

See here, if TalkBack fails to announce this as an image (which it will) the user still gets the idea that it is a picture.  You have added contextual information to the content description in a way that has ACTUALLY BETTER DESCRIBED THE CONTROL.  This is actually the most accessible solution!  Go figure.

Links:

For links this gets a bit tricky.  There is a great debate in Accessibility about what constitutes a link vs a button.  In the web browser world, this is a good debate.  However, in native mobile I think we have a very clear definition:

Any button that when activated takes you away from your current `Application Context`, is a link.

The fact that the Context (Capital C Context!!!) is going to change significantly when a user interacts with a control is EXCEPTIONALLY important information.

TalkBack fails to recognize links A LOT, and as such, for this very important piece of information, if you find that TalkBack is not sharing this information, go ahead and append ", link" to your content description for this element.  THIS IS THE ONLY EXCEPTION TO THIS RULE I HAVE FOUND, but believe it is a good exception.  Reason being, YES it does add a violation or two for other Assistive Technologies, but it conveys important enough information to justify doing so.  YOU CANNOT create a WCAG 2.0 compliant application of reasonable complex User Interface using the Android Accessibility APIs.  They have too many limitations, you simply can't do everything you need to do to accomplish this without "hacks".  So, we have to make judgement calls sometimes.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. This helps a lot.

Comment: Hi Chris, is your exception/hack for Links still valid in 2020? Do I need to append ", link" to a button's contentDescription that takes the user out of the app?

Comment: Yep, still accurate, unfortunately. Though the "back" action is used more pervasively now. So I would add that I would virtually never add ", link" to content descriptions myself, as the importance of things that take you out of context is diminished with the back action being so effective OS wide now. But, if you have a link that you wish to be communicated as a link, this is still the only way to do it. I just never do this in my own apps any more, and haven't seen a situation (since Android 9.0) in which I would recommend doing so.